# Git: split code modifications into several commits

Tags: git

Don't Know much about working with git.

I wonder if I have a file and made there a modifications lets say:

1. I modified lines 10-20 for adding feature ONE. But didn't (forget to) make a commit.
2. I modified lines 50-60 for adding feature TWO. An I want to make a commit.

How do I split this changes in to two commits? Is it possible?

Comment: What client are you using on what OS?

Comment: I'm on windows. Actually It would be interesting to do that with GitHub GUI client, but i seems that It doesn't support patches =(

Comment: If you would use Git Extensions you would have a UI that supports this. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with `git add -p`

See [`this page`](http://johnkary.net/blog/git-add-p-the-most-powerful-git-feature-youre-not-using-yet/) for a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `git add -p`.  This will break the changes up into patches that you can put into the commit.